# Save pages' data in JavaFX Pagination

Tags: java, javafx, pagination

I use a pagination control in my project, I ask users to add some text in every page ( Every page has textarea ) , when user changes the page data is cleared , How can I handle this problem ?

```
pagination.setPageFactory(this::getPage);

public Label getPage(int pageIndex) {


        Label content = null;
        if (pageIndex >= 0 && pageIndex < PAGE_COUNT) {
            content = new Label("Content for page " + (pageIndex + 1) + " / " + new Date());
            content.setId("Label" + pageIndex +1);
            //System.out.println(pageIndex+1);
        }

        return content;
    }
```

Comment: By reusing the text area instead of creating a new one? It's really impossible to tell why this is happening unless you can show some code.

Comment: In above code, How can I save the first date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code you have shown, you could create an array of strings, and then set the array elements when you create the pages. (You could just use an array of `Date`s if that were all the data you needed access to.)

```
private String[] data = new String[PAGE_COUNT];

// ...

pagination.setPageFactory(this::getPage);

public Label getPage(int pageIndex) {

    Label content = null;
    if (pageIndex >= 0 && pageIndex < PAGE_COUNT) {

        if (data[pageIndex] == null) {
            data[pageIndex] = "Content for page " + (pageIndex + 1) + " / " + new Date();
        }
        content = new Label(data[pageIndex]);
        content.setId("Label" + (pageIndex +1));
        //System.out.println(pageIndex+1);
    }

    return content;
}
```